# ActionScript - Is there a way to tell developer that this methods throws exception?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air

Like java, you can specify that method you are calling throws certain exception.
For e.g.-

`public void getListOfAssessments() throws SQLException;`

So, is there any way we can achieve this in ActionScript (Flex)?

Thanks,
Indrajit

Answer (score 4):

The only way I know is to use the `@throws` ASDocs tag. Example:

```
@throws SecurityError Local untrusted SWFs may not communicate with the Internet.
```

See this link for more information: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSd0ded3821e0d52fe1e63e3d11c2f44bc36-7ff6.html

Comment: ASDocs are for documentation purposes only; they do not change the way code behaves.

Comment: Yah although this is helpful information it doesn't cause the compiler to force the exception to be handled or explicitly thrown as is the case in Java (it's the lesser of the three things that bug me about AS3, other two being lack of threading and lack of overloading as I find them to be useful features in Java).  There is some sort of way to handle this with the "global error handler" http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvent.html

Answer (score 2):

Add a test to your test suite that shows that this is expected http://docs.flexunit.org/index.php?title=Exception_Handling . (Other developers on your team *are* reading your tests to see how your Classes behave, right?)